# Getting exported interface by implementing class name

Tags: c#, mef

I have various objects that implement a specific interface.
In one place in my code I get all the exports of the interfaces and save the actual class name in a DB. Here's some quick and dirty pseudo:

```
public interface ISomething { }

[Export(typeof(ISomething))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class Something : ISomething { }

[Export(typeof(ISomething))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class SomethingElse : ISomething { }

public class Handler {

    [Import]
    CompositionContainer _container;

    [ImportMany]
    IEnumerable<ISomething> _somethings;

    public void SaveSomething() {
        foreach(ISomething something in _somethings) {
            string className = something.GetType().Fullname;
            SaveToDatabase(className);
        }
    }
}
```

This works just fine and I can easily get all the ISomething implementations.
However, I also need to get a new instance of a specific classname at a later point.

If I try `_container.GetExportedValues<ISomething>` I get both `Something` and `SomethingElse`. If I try `_container.GetExportedValue<ISomething>("SomethingElse")` I get a composition error saying that it can't find any exports that match the constraint.

So, how can I get a new instance of `SomethingElse` by only knowing name of the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide two export attributes, so that you can import either by interface name or by your custom name.

Something like this:

```
public interface ISomething { }

[Export(typeof(ISomething))]
[Export("Something", typeof(ISomething))]
public class Something : ISomething { }

[Export(typeof(ISomething))]
[Export("SomethingElse", typeof(ISomething))]
public class SomethingElse : ISomething { }
```

Now, you can do this:

```
class Test
{
    [ImportMany]
    IEnumerable<ISomething> _somethings;

    [Import("SomethingElse", typeof(ISomething))]
    SomethingElse _somethingElse;
}
```

Comment: Ah, you can put the required contract name in the `[Export]` attribute... Clever. Is there any way to automatically put the fully qualified class name in the contract name? I can do `typeof(Something).FullName` in code, but not in the attribute.

Comment: @GTHvidsten, AFAIK, there is no way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to export the `SomethingElse` explicite:

```
[Export(typeof(SomethingElse))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class SomethingElse : ISomething { }
```

Then the `_container.GetExportedValue<SomethingElse>` works. It is also possible to export the same class with by giving a name the export.

```
[Export("SomethingElse", typeof(ISomething))]
```

Comment: Yes, but at that time the code doesn't know about the `SomethingElse` type. I only have a string containing the name of the `SomethingElse` class, not the class itself... and I will never have that reference either.